# Add Object to container in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add objects to a container in Powershell:

```
function Person {
  param ($FirstName, $LastName)
  $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    a=$FirstName;
    b=$LastName
  }
  return $object
}

$container = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

$result = Person "Billy" "Kid"
[void]$container.Add($result)

[void]$container.Add(Person "Bob" "Hope")
[void]$container.Add({Person "Mad" "Max"})

 foreach ($ob in $container) {
   Write-Output $ob."a"
 }

$container
```

This line:

```
[void]$container.Add($result)
```

works, meaning that the correct value gets printed in the foreach loop. But the lines:

```
[void]$container.Add(Person "Bob" "Hope")
[void]$container.Add({Person "Mad" "Max"})
```

does not. Is it not possible to add an element to the container using a function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the expression `Person "Bob" "Hope"` before you can add it.

You can do this easily like this:

```
$container.Add($(Person "Bob" "Hope"))
```

(Note the added `$()`).

Comment: The $ isn't necessary in this case. If you're doing string interpolation (`"hello $(Person "Hope" "Leslie"), are you hopeless?"`), then it is necessary.